# Yii2 how to pass the number of rows currently being displayed to view

Tags: listview, yii2

I have a problem with the number of rows currently being displayed in ListView widget. I don't know how to pass it to itemView.

My code:

```
 $count = $dataProvider->getCount();

    ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,        
        'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget, $count) {
            return $this->render('_item', [
                'model' => $model,
                'index' => $index,
                'count' => $count,                
            ]);
        },
        'pager' => Helper::getPagerSettings(),
    ]);
```

and it give me this error:

> Missing argument 5 for yii\base\View::{closure}()

but when I change $count = 0, it successful pass 0 to itemView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set number of items per page in ListView configure the pagination like:

```
ListView::widget([
    //...
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
]);
```

You are using closure to set `itemView` - it's ok but signature of this is

```
function ($model, $key, $index, $widget)
```

so there is no `$count`. If you want to pass additional argument do it like that (it works for every closure-type function):

```
function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) use ($count) {
    //...
}
```

I'm not sure what you use `$count` inside `itemView` for but to limit number of items per page use `pagination`.